# so big / big enough : difference

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

1. Something that's ***so big that*** it feels like a hassle to carry
   around.
2. Something that's ***big enough that*** it feels like a hassle to
   carry around.

I think I feel the difference, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

*Big enough* usually implies that being big is a good thing in that context, as in "The sign is big enough to be read from a distance". It is not really appropriate here, as we are talking about something that is *so big* that it is *too big* to be carried easily.